# How to convert a string input into a nested list in python without importing any module?

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists

For example

```
a = "((1|0)|(2|0)"
Make it into [[[1],"|",[0]],"|",[[2],"|",[0]]]
```

My approach to the question

I tried to let `a = (1|0)` and `b = (2|0)`, by using `str.index("|")` to split it in two halves, however it would only give me the first index of `"|"` which is 3, instead of 5 . Also I tried the `str.find("|")` and `str.rfind("|")`, but still it would not give me the correct index

Comment: Why does the string have unbalanced parentheses? Why would you want the integers in single-item lists? Have you tried splitting on `")|("`? It might be useful to say where the requirement and string come from, and whether you have any latitude on the format.

Comment: From the example output, it looks like the OP wants to create a new nested list either side of the `|` character whenever and wherever it may occur. Looks like recursion needs to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Is that python's freely shipped [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) library will do for you:

```
a = "((1|0)|(2|0)"
a = re.sub("(\d+)", "[\\1]", a) # digit into [x]
a = a.replace("(", "[")         # ( into [
a = a.replace(")", "]")         # ) into ]
print re.split("(\|)", a)       # spliting preserving the delimeter
```

Comment: I think the OP wants a list as an output, not a string

Comment: @jonrsharpe split returns `list()` say `some_list`. If it needs to convert the list into string, isn't `some_str = str(list_name)` will do it?

Comment: Title says without importing any module... ;)

Comment: @XORcist yeah thanks!. That's why I asked permission whether I can use the `re` or not. Looks like I missed the question mark(`?`) on the sentence :-P

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll answer a slightly different question: This version checks for balanced parens, throws away the splitters, and doesn't wrap the ints in an extra layer of list. In my experience, it's usually better that way if you're parsing things recursively.

```
def parse_element(s):
    '''Parse an element, return the remaining string'''
    if s[0] == '(':
        sub, rem = parse_chain(s[1:])
        if rem[0] != ')':
            raise ValueError('mismatched parens: %s' % (rem))
        return sub, rem[1:]
    if not s[0].isdigit():
        raise ValueError('expected element: %s' % (rem))
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if not c.isdigit():
            return int(s[:i]), s[i:]
    return int(s), ''

def parse_chain(s):
    '''Parse a chain of elements, return the remaining string'''
    chain = []
    cur = s
    while True:
        val, nxt = parse_element(cur)
        chain.append(val)
        if not nxt.startswith('|'):
            return chain, nxt
        cur = nxt[1:]

a = "((1|0)|(2|0))"
print parse_element(a)[0]
# prints: [[1, 0], [2, 0]]
```

However, here's the minor tweaks that answer the question as it was posed:

```
def parse_element(s):
    '''Parse an element, return the remaining string'''
    if s[0] == '(':
        sub, rem = parse_chain(s[1:])
        if rem == '':         # EDIT: added line
            return sub, rem   # EDIT: added line
        if rem[0] != ')':
            raise ValueError('mismatched parens: %s' % (rem))
        return sub, rem[1:]
    if not s[0].isdigit():
        raise ValueError('expected element: %s' % (rem))
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if not c.isdigit():
            return [int(s[:i])], s[i:]   # EDIT: added [] around int
    return [int(s)], ''                  # EDIT: added [] around int

def parse_chain(s):
    '''Parse a chain of elements, return the remaining string'''
    chain = []
    cur = s
    while True:
        val, nxt = parse_element(cur)
        chain.append(val)
        if not nxt.startswith('|'):
            return chain, nxt
        chain.append('|')     # EDIT: added line
        cur = nxt[1:]

print parse_element(a)[0]
a = "((1|0)|(2|0)"   # EDIT: removed paren (like original)
# prints: [[[1], '|', [0]], '|', [[2], '|', [0]]]
```